# How to use automatic intellisense in normal TextArea in a web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, intellisense

I am creating a Online compiler web application. Its finished and its running properly.Now I want to improve my application. I am trying to display intellisense in TextArea where the program is typing. For example, if I type Sys it should complete the word as System.

So far I tried from following URL:

Can anyone help me.

```
var demo_input = document.getElementById('demo_input');

var type_this = "see, I'm typing lots and lots of things magically!";
var index = 0;

window.next_letter = function() {
    if (index <= type_this.length) {
        demo_input.value = type_this.substr(0, index++);
        setTimeout("next_letter()", 50);
    }
}

next_letter();
```

[Automatic Filling](http://jsfiddle.net/Caut6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It not works

```
setTimeout("next_letter()", 50);
```

Please try to change

```
setTimeout(function() {
         next_letter(); 
    }, 50);
```